# How to fixed AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSequence'

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-dash, dashboard

I was trying to make a dash application. I have activated my virual environment and probably completed the code, but unfortunately, I have got this error.

> AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSequence'

So does anyone can help me this error?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your import statement to

```
from collections.abc import MutableSequence
```